# How to add a click event on child node of a flat tree node using angular 6

Tags: html, angular6

i am using this example
https://jdoypemleko.angular.stackblitz.io

when i am adding a click button in html page 
{{node.name}}

and a logNode function in component.ts file

i am only getting the click in the parent's node.But i want the click in all node especially the child node having no children.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: <button mat-button (click)="logNode(node)">{{node.name}}</button>

Comment: logNode(node){
    console.log(node)
  }

Comment: these code i just changed in the example. I am not able to resolve this